# Power efficiency of a dc motor

Tags: dc-motor

Is motor efficiency of dc motor independent from load (because I had read that it is about 85%) and also from which factors has an effect to efficiency of dc motor?

Comment: Certainly not! Just think about no load. Power goes in, nothing but heat and noise goes out. Is this homework?

Comment: Just spinning the motor is a load but what else is there. What size and type of motor is it? There are many different sizes, styles, and types of DC motors. Are the windings driven at design point, if not what is the deavation? Lots more information is needed you might ask the prof for the missing pieces.

Comment: @winny No it is not homework It is something that I thought when I read that It has 85 % motor efficiency

Comment: I see. Have you tried looking at datasheets for DC motors?

Comment: @winny No but I did a google right now datasheets for dc motor but I did not find something do you know where I can found (The power efficiency I read it from my book )

Comment: 85% is probably true for that particular motor at rated torque and speed.  Look up **DC Motor Efficiency Curve**  to get an idea of what a typical DC motor's efficiency looks like.

Answer (score 3):

> Is motor efficiency of dc motor independent from load

No. Trivially, at zero load, the efficiency is zero.

At very high load, we also know that the losses increase as current squared, while the torque varies as the current, and as the speed drops at high loads, the power output increases less than linearly with current, so the efficiency also drops.

This means the efficiency peaks at some intermediate load.